# Finding column names having commas in their data anywhere

Tags: python, pandas

I need to perform an operation on list of columns in which there is a comma anywhere in their data. Having more than 250columns and many rows.. I am unable to use explode() as I don't know which columns to use.

Below is the sample data
[image]

I want to separate the columns names i.e Cat2,Cat3,Cat4,Cat5

then I can work with the columns to explode/stack etc.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way to create a function and find them, just if anyone else is looking for a similar calculation.

```
def columns_with_commas_values(list):
    
    cols=[]

    for a in df.columns:
        if (df[a].str.contains(',') == True).any():
            cols.append(a)
        else:
            cols
    return(cols)
```